# sql server varbinary data output to azure blob

Tags: sql-server, azure-blob-storage, varbinary

I need output varbinary data (PDF) from sql server azure VM to blob. Is this possible? I have working code to export varbinary object to local drive, but I don't know how to export to azure blob storage.
Specifically tricky is to replace @DocumentName with blob path.

```
            EXEC sp_OACreate 'ADODB.Stream', @ObjectToken OUTPUT
            EXEC sp_OASetProperty @ObjectToken, 'Type', 1
            EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Open'
            EXEC sp_OAMethod @ObjectToken, 'Write', NULL, @Document     
            SET @DocumentName = 'I:\test\'filename'.pdf'
```

Comment: Can't you use regular BULK INSERT? See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-ver16 for how to work with it

Answer (score 0):

I tried with below procedure to copy data from local drive to Azure blob storage:
I created blob storage and created container.

[image]

I generated SAS token of then storage account:

[image]

I copied the container path and SAS token.
I am using windows OS that's why I downloaded the azcopy module related to windows 64 bit and I copied that to C:\Windows\System32 and run below command in command prompt.

```
azcopy.exe
```

[image]

I used below command to copy data to azure blob storage:

```
azcopy.exe copy "<filepath>" "<containerpath>/<SAStoken>" --recursive
```

[image]

My file is successfully copied to azure blob storage:

[image]

It worked fine for me. you can check this once from your end.